# Simple Azure Table Service front-end for jQuery site

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, azure-table-storage

I'm developing a jQuery website that will display a single record from my Azure Table Storage (ATS) account. I don't want to use jQuery to directly access the table, since that would require disclosure of my ATS account name and key in the jQuery code. I've tried to find a simple C# web service example project that would be the interface, but everything I can find is much more complicated than I need.

This web service will need just one API that jQuery will use: it will be passed  two strings: the Partition Key and the Row Key for ATS, which will exactly match with an existing record in ATS. The result returned will be a string that jQuery will convert using JSON.parse() after it is received. If no record is found with the Partition and Row Keys passed in, an empty string should be returned.

If you know of an example of a simple C# web service that I could use as a starting point, I would greatly appreciate a link to it. It's been many years since I developed with C#, and the complicated nature of the table service API with all the associated crypto, hashing, signatures, etc. have left me confused.

Edit: I now realize that maybe both my jQuery code (providing the web UI) and the C# (providing the ATS interface) might work together in one .NET solution. I'm currently running the jQuery UI app standalone in its own .NET solution, due to my path of fumbling around trying things out.

Comment: Just create a new ASP.NET Web Api project, make the one controller and one action you need and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use jQuery to directly access the table, since that would require disclosure of my ATS account name and key in the jQuery code.

It seems that you do not want jQuery client directly make a GET request to query entity via [table service Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities), and you’d like to create a backend service for querying entity in table. As maccettura mentioned in comment, you can create a ASP.NET Web API project and do `Query Entities` operation in controller action.

```
[Route("queryentity/{pk}/{rk}")]
public CustomerEntity Get(string pk, string rk)
{
    //you can install [Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)
    //and then create a retrieve operation and pass both partition and row keys to retrieve a single entity

    //TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CustomerEntity>(pk, rk);

    //or 
    //make [Query Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities) operation as you did 


    return myCustomerEntity;
}
```